# Varnish - double quotes in conditionals

Tags: varnish-vcl

Running Varnish 4.x - trying to test for  "-" including the double quotes.

```
if (req.url == **'"-"'**) {
    return (synth(200, "ok"));
}
```

Can't find the right escape character to include the double quotes in the conditional statement.   Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try escaping with `%22`?

```
if (req.url == "%22-%22") {
  return (synth(200, "ok"));
}
```

Comment: This would only work in _Fastly_ VCL, which supports percent-encoding. Stock VCL does not.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this issue. From 6.x on (at least) you should be able to use the `{"..."}` notation:

```
if (req.url == **{""-""}**) {
    return (synth(200, "ok"));
}
```

See https://varnish-cache.org/docs/6.6/reference/vcl.html#strings